# How to replace Twenty Seventeen Wordpress header with slider?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I would like my header to be replaced by my slider made with the Master Slider widget. I want the slider to be full size, just like the header image is right now.

This is the header code:

```
<?php
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js no-svg">
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="site">
<a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?></a>

<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/header/header', 'image' ); ?>

    <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'top' ) ) : ?>
        <div class="navigation-top">
            <div class="wrap">
                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/navigation/navigation', 'top' ); ?>
            </div><!-- .wrap -->
        </div><!-- .navigation-top -->
    <?php endif; ?>

</header><!-- #masthead -->

<?php
// If a regular post or page, and not the front page, show the featured image.
if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ( is_single() || ( is_page() && ! twentyseventeen_is_frontpage() ) ) ) :
    echo '<div class="single-featured-image-header">';
    the_post_thumbnail( 'twentyseventeen-featured-image' );
    echo '</div><!-- .single-featured-image-header -->';
endif;
?>

<div class="site-content-contain">
    <div id="content" class="site-content">
```

The shortcode for my slider is:
[masterslider id="1"]

PHP function:
`<?php masterslider(1); ?>`

How can I insert this image slider to replace the header image on the front page only without affecting the rest of the page?

Thanks.

Comment: "Front page only..."  You need to understand how the WordPress template hierarchy works.  check out [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

Comment: `<?php  if (twentyseventeen_is_frontpage()) : masterslider(1); endif; ?>` should work...

Comment: @zipzit where do I put this code? and do I need to delete any of the other code? I inserted it in but it did nothing.

Comment: Are you using the developer tools in the Chrome browser?  What does the source code look like in the browser?  At that master slider line?  Remember php functions are all called from the server. JavaScript functions run in the users browser.

Comment: Try this `<?php if (twentyseventeen_is_frontpage()) {
    masterslider(1);} endif; ?>`  Place this code in the header.php file, right before `</header>`    Note: lets see if this works.  If it does, then you have to add a php if statement to hide other stuff on that front page...